# Probability and random process

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There are 50 books belonging to 50 students. I distribute them back with out seeing the name. What is the average no of students who will get back their own books

Comment: Try showing your own work so far, it may get more attention to the question. Have you tried this for a smaller number of students?

Comment: Have you heard of linearity of expectation ?

Comment: there result should be $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expectation that any student $k$ will get their original book is $\mathsf E(X_k)= \mathsf P(X_k{=}1)$ where we count $X_k {=} 1 $ iff the student receives their original book and $X_k{=}0$ otherwise.

What is this probability?

Then expected count of students who receive their original book is: $\mathsf E(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{50} X_k)$

How are these expectations related?